# Get the exact jSpinner Value

Tags: java, netbeans, time, jspinner

Can somebody tell me how can I get the exact value from jSpinner?
Here is how my jSpinner's appear when user will select time:
[image]

however, when I pass the jSpinner value to textfield it appears like this: [image]

Here is my code:

```
timeout1 = spnrTOH1.getValue()+":"+spnrTOM1.getValue()+" "+spnrTOA1.getValue();
```

Here is my jSpinner model:
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!
Sorry if my question seems silly. Newbie here. :)

Comment: i checked the code. working fine.. whats the issue?? on which event you want to display it on textfield.??

Comment: Hi @NiRRaNjANRauT , I want to have 01:00 AM and not 1:0 AM. I want to display on textfield when the submit button is triggered. thanks

Comment: what `model` you had set to `JSpinner`...means `DefaultModel` or any other...

Comment: I've set it as number. I'll edit my question and add the screenshot of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this function to your program..

```
public String getString(Object object) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(object.toString().trim());
    if(number < 10) {
        return "0" + number;
    }
    return String.valueOf(number);
}
```

and call this when you have to set the value to text field like

```
timeout1 = getString(spnrTOH1.getValue())+":"+getString(spnrTOM1.getValue())+" "+spnrTOA1.getValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not related to spinner nor its model.

You need to format your string to have leading zeros. The spinner is showing `00` when the exact value is `0` due to spiner's renderer formatting procedure. Renderer is a component that is responsible for showing on GUI value held by the model. Eg. Custom renderer can display integers as Roman numbers.

To format your output simply use `String#format` method like that:

```
timeout1 = String.format("%02d:%02d %s",spnrTOH1.getValue(),spnrTOM1.getValue(),spnrTOA1.getValue());
```

This way you will display integer values as 2 digits numbers with leading 0.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer. But the first answer works for me. I appreciate your help. Big Thanks! :)